# AngularJS - error passing a controller in the html from ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a portal style application that will inject html from other urls (within domain) into portions of the page. Let's call them widgets. I want each widget to be loaded with a ng-include.

The widget should have it's own controller included in the returned html. I need these to be self-contained because the list of widgets changes per user. I cannot seem to get the widget html to load anything but a global controller. I'm using Grails server side so ignore the ${} tags.

In my application, GreetingController works. If I use GridCtrlr I get this error:
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/ng/areq?p0=GridCtrlr&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

I have another controller that is loaded on the page that works fine so I know angular is running ok.

Do I have to use a global controller in this instance or can I use one within the application scope?

Here is the ng-include on the home page:

```
<div ng-include="'${createLink(controller:"testGrid", action:"index")}'"></div>
```

This is my controllers.js file:

```
var portalLayoutTool = angular.module('portalLayoutTool', []);

portalLayoutTool.controller('BootstrapCtrl', function ($scope) {
   //Do stuff here...
}
```

Here is the html returned by the ng-include showing the two styles of creating controllers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    portalLayoutTool.controller('GridCtrlr', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
    });

    function GreetingController($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
    }


</script>
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help you can give. This must be a pretty simple issue but AngularJS takes some getting used to!

Actually, neither controller style works in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BU0uqmhEbvHEqJfTeGg4?p=preview

Comment: Your widget approach seems misguided. Take a look at directives, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

Code seems a bit weird and I am not sure I understand all you are trying to accomplish, but...

If you pull the JS out of the html file and keep the template only a template and allow the JS to be instantiated at the beginning of the page load then you will have something working, whether or not its what you are looking for I can't say but at least its a step forward.

Here is your forked plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AyVhmIum9ohsER7lKMNk?p=preview

Comment: I want the widget to be a self-contained piece of code including the UI and Javascript and not need it's controller declared when the page loads originally. The page may have different widgets loaded for each user based on the user's role.